# Foundation Orbit slider, show nav on small screens

Tags: zurb-foundation, orbit

The Orbit slider that comes as part of [Zurb's Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) seems to add a class of `hide-for-small` to the navigation.

I need the navigation to still show up however in order to show my content. I have tried removing the `hide-for-small` part of the wrapper in jquery.foundation.orbit.js line 59 but the class keeps getting added.

Does anyone have an idea how to remove it?

Comment: In the end I've overridden the CSS of hide-for-small within the given context but it doesn't feel like the best solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: Please see jmsg1990's answer as it is the proper way to do this now.

Just ran into this problem myself and solved it quite easily by opening up jquery.foundation.orbit.js.

**At line 60**:

```
directionalNavHTML: '<div class="slider-nav hide-for-small"><span class="right"></span><span class="left"></span></div>'
```

Simply remove the class "hide-for-small" like below and it works as expected.

```
directionalNavHTML: '<div class="slider-nav"><span class="right"></span><span class="left"></span></div>'
```

Answer (score 4):

You should add `.touch .orbit-bullets { display: block; }` to your css. Foundation 4 adds the `.touch` class when using a touch-enabled device, which hides orbit's bullets and arrows.

Comment: This should actually be marked as the correct answer. Much better for updating Foundation in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, add the following to your app.css to over-ride the class:

```
.hide-for-small {
  display: block !important;
}
```

It's more future-proof if you upgrade your Foundation someday.

Comment: You would want to make sure to apply this ONLY to the Orbit bullets, otherwise the hide-for-small class won't work for other items.